# Two Singletons in one application - both with different @Scheduled methods - one class method waits for the other?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, apache-tomee

The following code replicates the issue.

Class TestA:

```
package main.java.monitor;

import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class TestA {

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*")
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Test A started");
        System.out.println("Test A finished");
    }

}
```

Class TestB:

```
package main.java.monitor;

import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class TestB {

    @Schedule(hour="*", minute="*", second="*")
    public void run() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Test B started");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Test B finished");
    }

}
```

Expected output (something like) would be Test A started, Test A finished 10 times more often than Test B started and Test B finished, but actual output is (with added date/time):

```
Test A started Tue Feb 03 13:09:47 GMT 2015
Test A finished Tue Feb 03 13:09:47 GMT 2015
Test B started Tue Feb 03 13:09:47 GMT 2015
Test A started Tue Feb 03 13:09:48 GMT 2015
Test A finished Tue Feb 03 13:09:48 GMT 2015
Test A started Tue Feb 03 13:09:49 GMT 2015
Test A finished Tue Feb 03 13:09:49 GMT 2015
Test B finished Tue Feb 03 13:09:57 GMT 2015
Test B started Tue Feb 03 13:09:57 GMT 2015
Test A started Tue Feb 03 13:09:58 GMT 2015
Test A finished Tue Feb 03 13:09:58 GMT 2015
Test B finished Tue Feb 03 13:10:07 GMT 2015
Test B started Tue Feb 03 13:10:07 GMT 2015
Test A started Tue Feb 03 13:10:08 GMT 2015
Test A finished Tue Feb 03 13:10:08 GMT 2015
```

Anyone able to shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'll see it pretty clear adding on your EJBs @AccessTimeout(0)

in 2 words: you singletons are @Lock(WRITE) by default and B is locking (executed each second but waiting 10). Once the async pool is full (default is 3 threads) then no more thread is available and invocation is waiting a slot to be released by B.